# SATA devices not recognized by BIOS

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, sata

I recently completed a build using an ASUS M5A97 R2.0 motherboard. I booted the computer for the first time, went to intall Ubuntu from a USB drive, and my HDD was not shown in the menu for installation location. I checked the 'SATA Configuration' section in the MB's BIOS and saw that every SATA port read 'Not present', despite having both and HDD and ODD correctly installed (99% sure about that) into the computer. Not sure what is wrong here, all SATA ports are 6gb/s. I've enabled the ports that the devices are plugged into to no avail. Help?

Answer (score 0):

BIOS usually has options for SATA to be a choice of Legacy, AHCI or RAID which if not set correct means your OS might not see the drives.  However, the motherboard BIOS should be able to see the drives.  Have you:

1. checked the drives in another PC
2. checked your cables work with other known working drives?
3. checked to see the drives have power, ODD should be able to open tray with power, HDD will make some noise on power-on with SATA cabled attached or not.

Comment: My ODD doesn't open, though I plugged the power cable in.

Comment: Suggest power is not on the cable then or the ODD is dead.  However, I would think you are not powering your devices, trace the cables all the way back to the PSU. If using a modular cable ensure those cables are pushed all the way in.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what exactly is a modular cable (this is my first bulid)?

Comment: Sorry I should say modular PSU - is it a PSU where you can remove cables, if so it is modular. If all the power cables are fixed in place then it is non-modular.

Comment: Oh, in that case it is non-modular.

Comment: Just so we are clear the ODD and HDD have two connections each - one for data (The SATA Cable) and one for Power. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that.

Comment: And your HDD spins up when it is powered on?

Comment: Not sure, should I leave the case open while booting to feel for it?

Comment: You should be able to hear or feel vibrations as it spins up. I guess you will need to have the cover off in that case.

Comment: No spinning on the hard drive.